# How can I change the text of each button in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've looked around SO and tried the solutions offered, but I can't seem to change the `text` of any `button` I've made using a double `for` loop.

The loops are there so I can add them to a `list` of `lists` of `buttons` so I can (supposedly) access them conveniently through the nested list by calling `board_button[2][3]` or something. They are also dynamically created after the user inputs the `board_size` such that it generates a grid of nxn buttons so there's that. These are all done inside a class method, and there's another class method that should change the `button`'s `text` when it's called by the button.

I've tried using the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615440/python-3-tkinter-how-to-update-button-text), but none of them actually worked for my problem.

Pardon the long block of code, but I honestly think the way I've made it may have contributed to the problem, and give more insight as result.

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow(Frame):

    board_size = None
    file_input = None
    board_buttons = None
    board_strvars = None

    row = []

    def __init__ (self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # initialize widgets but don't show them yet
        self.initWidgets()
        # show the starting window
        self.startWindow()

    def generateBoard(self, to_forget=None):
        # hides the groups of the method that called it
        if to_forget != None:
            for i in to_forget:
                self.row[i].forget()

        # get the board_size from user
        self.board_size = int(self.size_entry.get())

        # initialize text variables for each button
        self.board_strvars = []
        for i in range(self.board_size):
            self.row_strvars=[]
            for j in range(self.board_size):
                var = StringVar()
                var.set("   ")
                self.row_strvars.append(var)

            self.board_strvars.append(self.row_strvars)

        # insert list of lists of buttons here
        self.row[1].pack(fill=X)

        self.board_buttons = []
        for i in range(self.board_size):
            self.row_buttons=[]
            for j in range(self.board_size):
                self.row_buttons.append(Button(self.row[1], textvariable=self.board_strvars[i][j], command=lambda:self.place(i, j)))
                self.row_buttons[j].grid(row=i, column=j)

            self.board_buttons.append(self.row_buttons)

        # for solve and back button
        self.row[2].pack(fill=X)

    def initWidgets(self):
        # create the rows or groups of widgets
        for i in range(3):
            self.row.append(Frame())

        # row 0; startWindow
        self.size_entry = Entry(self.row[0])
        self.size_entry.pack(fill=X, side=LEFT)

        self.size_button = Button(self.row[0], text="Enter", command=lambda:self.generateBoard([0]))
        self.size_button.pack(fill=X, side=LEFT)

        self.load_button = Button(self.row[0], text="Load", command=self.loadFile)
        self.load_button.pack(fill=X, side=LEFT)


        # row 2; generateBoard
        self.solve_button = Button(self.row[2], text="Solve", command=self.showSolutions)
        self.solve_button.pack(fill=X, side=LEFT)

        self.back_button = Button(self.row[2], text="Back", command=lambda:self.startWindow(to_forget=[0,2], to_destroy=[1]))
        self.back_button.pack(fill=X, side=RIGHT)

    def loadFile(self):
        print("file loaded!")

    def place(self, i, j):
        if self.board_strvars[i][j].get() == "   ":
            self.board_strvars[i][j].set("C")
        else:
            self.board_strvars[i][j].set("   ")

    def showSolutions(self):
        print("solutions shown!")


    def startWindow(self, to_forget=None, to_destroy=None):
        # hides the groups of the method that called it
        if to_forget != None:
            for i in to_forget:
                self.row[i].forget()

        # destroys the groups' child widgets and hides the group
        if to_destroy != None:
            for i in to_destroy:
                for child in self.row[i].winfo_children():
                    child.destroy()
                self.row[i].forget()

        self.row[0].pack(fill=X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title("test")
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I originally wanted to define a function that will change the `text` of the `button` that called it. But so far I've found no way to do so.

Doing the solutions offered in the post I linked changes nothing to the buttons. In the code I provided though, I used the `StringVar()` to be assigned as `textvariable` of the `button`. However, it only changes the last row, last column button element no matter which button you click. It's supposed to work in a way that the button that was clicked, will get its text changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `lambda` function to force a closure:

```
def generateBoard(self, to_forget=None):
    ...

    for i in range(self.board_size):
        self.row_buttons=[]
        for j in range(self.board_size):
            self.row_buttons.append(Button(self.row[1], textvariable=self.board_strvars[i][j], command=lambda i=i, j=j:self.place(i, j)))
            self.row_buttons[j].grid(row=i, column=j)

        self.board_buttons.append(self.row_buttons)
```

Also note that its better to not call your own method `place` since there is already a `place` method in Tk.