# How do I change the text of Tkinter Buttons in a List

Tags: python, tkinter

So my friend challenged me to make something with Python.
I haven't really done Python before, so I'm struggling with quite a few things.

I have a 9 buttons

```
turn7 = Button(root, text='', relief="flat", font=("arial", 28, "bold"), width=3, command=lambda: doTurn(turn7,7))
```

I create every one of the buttons like this and then append them in a list:

```
_list.append([turn1,turn2,turn3,turn4,turn5,turn6,turn7,turn8,turn9])
```

I'm trying to change the text of all the buttons like this:

```
for turn in _list:
    turn["text"] = "Text"
```

But it returns: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615440/python-3-tkinter-how-to-update-button-text - does this help?

Comment: Try changing `_list.append(...)` to `_list.extend(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, list.extend() fixed it.
And the TextVariable method is actually pretty handy too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3, Tkinter, How to update button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615440/python-3-tkinter-how-to-update-button-text)

Comment: When you write ```turn["text"]```, you can't have a string. You need to have a number, so you need to do ```_list[turn]``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your list looks like `[[turn1,turn2,turn3,turn4,turn5,turn6,turn7,turn8,turn9]]`, not `[turn1,turn2,turn3,turn4,turn5,turn6,turn7,turn8,turn9]`. Use `_list += [turn1,turn2,turn3,turn4,turn5,turn6,turn7,turn8,turn9]` instead. Hope that's helpful!