# Is there a way to change the text of the button when the button clicked

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Is there a way to change the text of the button when the button clicked?

edit: nvm I solved its like text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3, Tkinter, How to update button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615440/python-3-tkinter-how-to-update-button-text)

Comment: sorry but no. I cant understand that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you to solve your issue. Using `.config()` you can update a button in tkinter

```
from tkinter import Button,Tk


root = Tk()


def click():
    b.config(text='You jus clicked me!')


b = Button(root, text='Click me', command=click)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: but My Python IDE says:NameError: name 'b' is not defined (in def)

Comment: did u name ur button variable b? or something else

Comment: i dont named button named b, but my variable is "menu", so i used this: menu.config(text="You jus clicked me!")

Comment: somewhere in your code, so mentioned b, did u `pack` it using b?. can u post ur code of button nd function in here

Comment: def click():
    menu.config(text='You jus clicked me!')


menu = Button(root, text='Click me', command=click)
menu.pack()

Comment: wait i found a issue; i packed b not menu thanks for supporting me anyway