# when I push a button in Tkinter nothing happens

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter so sorry if the solution is obvious. In tkinter I made a button. And I made a def`myClick: for something to happen when the button is pressed. But nothing happens after the button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def myClick():
    myLabel1 = Label(root, text="you clicked me")
    myLabel1.pack
myButton = Button(root, text="click me!", padx=50, command=myClick())
myButton.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command = myClick`, no brackets.  Command is a function, not the result of running the function.

Answer (score 2):

I found a few problems. Here's my version which might be of help to you:

1. You had `command=myClick()` but it should be `command=myClick` instead (without parentheses). If you have parentheses, it invokes the function once when it first loads your code. But if you pass it without parentheses, then it will be invoked every time you click the button. You can read more on this topic [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-function-as-an-argument-in-python/).
2. You had `myLabel1.pack` but it should be `myLabel1.pack()`. Here you didn't put parentheses so you didn't actually invoke the function. That's a part why nothing was happening.
3. I changed `myButton.grid(row=1, column=1)` to `myButton.pack()` because there seemed to be some problem with mixing `grid()` and `pack()` methods. I'm new to tkinter myself, so there might be a simple solution for using both. But for the time being I changed it.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def myClick():
    print("hello")
    myLabel1 = Label(root, text="you clicked me")
    myLabel1.pack()
myButton = Button(root, text="click me!", padx=50, command=myClick)
myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Under a single container, only `grid()` or `pack()` can be used, both cannot be used together.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem.

Comment: @Tgsadman ~ Consider marking this as the correct answer if this answered your question correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Answer (score 0):

From: [Python 3, Tkinter, How to update button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615440/python-3-tkinter-how-to-update-button-text)

You can use the text variable option of the Button class. The code could be the following:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def myClick():
    print("Click")
    bot_text.set("you clicked me")
    myButton.text="you clicked me"

bot_text = StringVar()
myButton = Button(root, textvariable=bot_text, padx=50, command=myClick)
bot_text.set("Click me!")
myButton.grid(row=1, column=1)
myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why use `textvariable`.