# Rng for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game and utilizing tkinter for framing. I'm able to create the buttons for player aka "X" and changes when the button is pressed but for the computer or "O" I can't seem to find how to rng the button press to change the button text.

I have the algorithm working for the program I'm just trying use tkinters framing to make it more visually appealing.

Comment: Are you aware python has a module named [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) that can be used to generate random numbers?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations. What do you mean by "rng"?

Comment: Yes, I have the whole program working, including random for computer.  I just don't know how to generate random event in tkinter to simulate computer button press...

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk RNG = Random Number Generator, this is a well-known abbreviation.

Comment: @Barmar: Of course I know that definition, but it makes no sense in the context of OPs question.

Comment: Why do you think adding tkinter for the UI makes any difference to how you generate the moves randomly?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I don't understand where is the confusion?

Comment: You shouldn't generate moves randomly. You should use an algorithm to select the best move to prevent the opponent from winning.

Comment: @Barmar I can't figure out how to simulate that.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that is the next step but for now I need a way to simulate computer pick with tkinter.

Comment: If you have a list of elements where you display the moves, you select a random element of the list, and then set its text to `O`.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's what I'm doing and that portion is working but how do I get text to populate the button on tkinter after players turn?

Comment: What is the issue? If you know how to change the text of the player's button, you use the same method to change the text of the computer's button. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615440/python-3-tkinter-how-to-update-button-text

Comment: That thread helps, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.